# How to remove elements of lists in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to filter out pesky ***None*** values from a dictionary of lists. Here is an example dictionary:

```
parsed_data = {'DATA1': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '0.17998362', '0.06388072',
     '0.02091766', None, '0.00602364', '0.03171121', None, '1.39579976', '0.16731957',
     '0.21564664', '0.03516583'], 'DATA2': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
     None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'DATA3':
     [None, None, None, None], 'DATA4': ['0.18406565', '0.06776296', '0.14278403',
     '0.11962064', '0.00998447']}
```

I thought this dictionary comprehension would work, but it removes the entire key if it finds ***None*** anywhere in the list.

```
filtered = {x:y for x,y in parsed_data.items() if len(y)>0 and None not in y}
```

I also tried doing a dictionary comprehension with a nested list comprehension but it looked insane and made by brain melt a little just by looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the elements in the list filtering the Nones and keeping everything else, if you want to change the original just update each list:

```
for v in parsed_data.values():
        v[:] = (ele for ele in v if ele is not None)
```

Or if you want a new dict:

```
 new = {k : [ele for ele in v if ele is not None] for k,v in parsed_data.items()}
```

Both will give you:

```
{'DATA1': ['0.17998362',
           '0.06388072',
           '0.02091766',
           '0.00602364',
           '0.03171121',
           '1.39579976',
           '0.16731957',
           '0.21564664',
           '0.03516583'],
 'DATA2': [],
 'DATA3': [],
 'DATA4': ['0.18406565',
           '0.06776296',
           '0.14278403',
           '0.11962064',
           '0.00998447']}
```

If you are using python 3, you can use combine filter into the first logic using *None.**ne***:

```
for v in parsed_data.values():
        v[:] = filter(None.__ne__, v)
```

Comment: I've never seen [:] before. What is it doing?

Comment: @Chris, it updates the list in place, lists are mutable so any changes are reflected wherever there is a  reference to it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `dict` comprehension then assign it back to `parsed_data`

```
parsed_data = {key: [i for i in value if i] for key, value in parsed_data.items()}
```

Output

```
{'DATA2': [],
 'DATA3': [],
 'DATA1': ['0.17998362', '0.06388072', '0.02091766', '0.00602364', '0.03171121', '1.39579976', '0.16731957', '0.21564664', '0.03516583'],
 'DATA4': ['0.18406565', '0.06776296', '0.14278403', '0.11962064', '0.00998447']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dic, set the value of each key to be an empty list, and then append to each list the values that are !=None

```
new_arsed_data={}
for key,value in arsed_data.items():
    new_arsed_data.setdefault(key,[])
    for item in value:
        if item!=None:
            new_arsed_data[key].append(item)
```

It's a more convoluted/less pythonic answer compared to the others, but maybe more understandable for someone who (like me) is new to python :)